# How to read Xsens IMU output values (measurement unit)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm using a xsens MTI-10 IMU sensor (the orange version) and I would like to know how to read the output values.

For example, I get these kind of readings:

```
header: 
  seq: 620
  stamp: 
    secs: 1466618458
    nsecs: 864463090
  frame_id: /base_imu
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 0.0
orientation_covariance: [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 32650.0
  y: 32783.0
  z: 32780.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 33146.0
  y: 35201.0
  z: 36234.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

How do I have to read these numbers (for example,  x: 32650.0)? Are they radiants or degrees?

Can you help me, please?

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237806/how-to-read-xsens-imu-output-values-(measurement-unit)/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-06-22**:
may be, they are only raw data and then I need to convert them in order to obtein the correct values? If so, I can't find the conversion formula..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you getting this readings? Are you accessing the IMU using a UART on your computer, creating the message and the publishing what you get?

In any case, something is wrong with the code you are using, the quaternion should indicate a vector of norm equal to one. All elements are equal to zero on what you shared.

cheers...

---

Originally posted by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) with karma: 106 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2016-06-23**:
The problem was related to the raw data.
I changed the output mode and now I'm able to correctly read the values.

Thank you for your help!